# pytorch autoencoder model evaluation fail

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am literally a beginner of PyTorch.
I trained an autoencoder network so that I can plot the distribution of the latent vectors (the result of encoders).

This is the code that I used for network training.

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob

dir_img_decoded = '/media/dohyeong/HDD/mouth_autoencoder/dc_img_2'
if not os.path.exists(dir_img_decoded):
    os.mkdir(dir_img_decoded)

dir_check_point = '/media/dohyeong/HDD/mouth_autoencoder/ckpt_2'
if not os.path.exists(dir_check_point):
    os.mkdir(dir_check_point)

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

num_epochs = 200
batch_size = 150  # up -> GPU memory increase
learning_rate = 1e-3

dir_dataset = '/media/dohyeong/HDD/mouth_autoencoder/mouth_crop/dir_normalized_mouth_cropped_images'
images = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_dataset, '*.png'))
train_images = images[:-113]
test_images = images[-113:]

train_images.sort()
test_images.sort()





class TrumpMouthDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images):
        super(TrumpMouthDataset, self).__init__()
        self.images = images

        self.transform = transforms.Compose([
            # transforms.Resize((28, 28)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        ])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image = Image.open(self.images[index])

        return self.transform(image)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)


train_dataset = TrumpMouthDataset(train_images)
test_dataset = TrumpMouthDataset(test_images)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(60000, 60),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(60, 3),
            nn.ReLU(True),
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(3, 60),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(60, 60000),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

        return encoded, decoded


model = Autoencoder().cuda()
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    model = nn.DataParallel(model)
    model.to(device)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                             lr=learning_rate,
                             weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    total_loss = 0

    for index, imgs in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        imgs = imgs.to(device)

        # ===================forward=====================
        outputs = model(imgs)

        imgs_flatten = imgs.view(imgs.size(0), -1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, imgs_flatten)

        # ===================backward====================
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

        print('{} Epoch, [{}/{}] batch, loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, index + 1, len(train_dataloader), loss.item()))

    avg_loss = total_loss / len(train_dataset)
    print('{} Epoch, avg_loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, avg_loss))


    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        check_point_file = os.path.join(dir_check_point, str(epoch) + ".pth")
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), check_point_file)
```

After training, I tried to get encoded values using this code.

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

check_point = '/media/dohyeong/HDD/mouth_autoencoder/290.pth'
model = torch.load(check_point)

for index, imgs in enumerate(train_dataloader):

    imgs = imgs.to(device)

    # ===================evaluate=====================
    encoded, _ = model(imgs)
```

It finished with this error message.
"TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable"
May I get some help?

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to the PyTorch community :D

### TL;DR

Change `model = torch.load(check_point)` to `model.load_state_dict(torch.load(check_point))`.

---

The only problem is with the line:

```py
model = torch.load(check_point)
```

The way you saved the checkpoint was:

```py
torch.save(model.state_dict(), check_point_file)
```

That is, you saved the model's `state_dict` (which is just a dictionary of the various parameters that together describe the current instance of the model) in `check_point_file`.

Now, in order to load it back, just reverse the process.
`check_point_file` contains just the `state_dict`.

It knows nothing about the internals of the model - what it's architecture is, how it's supposed to work etc.

So, load it back:

```py
state_dict = torch.load(check_point)
```

This `state_dict` can now be copied onto your Model instance as follows:

```py
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

Or, more succinctly,

```py
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(check_point))
```

You got the error because the `torch.load(check_point)` returned the `state_dict` *which you assigned to `model`.*

When you subsequently called `model(imgs)`, `model` was an `OrderedDict` object (not callable).

Hence the error.

See the [Serialization Semantics Notes](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/serialization.html) for more details.

Apart from that, your code sure is thorough for a beginner. Great going!

---

P.S. Your device agnosticity is brilliant! Perhaps you'd want to take a look at:

1. the line `model = Autoencoder().cuda()`
2. The `map_location` argument of [`torch.load()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.load)